# Trigger rebuild of other widgets after FutureBuilder finishes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a page with two main widgets: a futurebuilder that contains a list of elements taken from an api and an appbar.
The appbar content (a row of days) is grayed out depending on the result of the api (which returns a list of dates). When I interact with the appbar, that has a button to update the data from the api, it triggers a rebuild (with setstate I update the future with the api call). However, when FutureBuilder finishes and updates the state with the result, the appbar does not refresh. How can I force an update? I tried calling setstate from inside the futurebuilder but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you did not put FutureBuilder Widget on top of you app bar.

Comment: you mean the appbar as a child of FutureBuilder?